# Problem with seperating one String into two arrays (words seperated by Tab and Enter)

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

EDIT 02.10.2022 - Got it working, have a look at the End.

I am trying to make a program that splits one string of text into to arrays
the input in the String text looks as following:

```
voc1    deut1
voc2    deut2
voc3    deut3
voc4    deut4
```

the 2 separate String[] arrays should be filled as following:

```
splits[0]="voc1"
splits[1]="voc2"
splits[2]="voc3"
splits[3]="voc4"

lines[0]="deut1"
lines[1]="deut2"
lines[2]="deut3"
lines[3]="deut4"
```

The first of both work perfectly [0], but from then on
it collapses into a horrible mess like [1]:

```
splits[1]: deut2
voc3
lines[1]: voc2  deut2
```

Here is the old version:

```java
public class raplacer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text= "voc1  deut1\nvoc2 deut2\nvoc3 deut3\nvoc4 deut4";

        String[] splits = null;
        String[] lines = null;
        int numbSplits =0;
        int numbLines =0;

        for(int i=0; i<3;i++) {
            System.out.print("nextLine:  " + text.indexOf("\n"));
            System.out.println("    nextTab:   " + text.indexOf("   "));
            if(text.indexOf("\n")>text.indexOf("    ")) {
                splits=text.split(" ");
                splits[numbSplits+1]="";
                text=text.replaceFirst(splits[numbSplits], "");
                System.out.println("Text:\n" + text);
                text=text.replaceFirst("    ", "");
                System.out.println("Text:\n" + text);
                numbSplits++;
                System.out.println("Splitet a Tab away");
            }
            else if(text.indexOf("\n")<text.indexOf("   ")) {
                lines=text.split("\n");
                lines[numbLines+1]="";
                text=text.replaceFirst(lines[numbLines], "");
                System.out.println("Text:\n" + text);
                text=text.replaceFirst("\n", "");
                System.out.println("Text:\n" + text);
                numbLines++;
                System.out.println("Splited a Line away");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Text:\n" + text);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("splits0: " + splits[0]);
        System.out.println("splits1: " + splits[1]);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("lines0: " + lines[0]);
        System.out.println("lines1: " + lines[1]);
    }
}
```

EDIT 02.10.2022 - I got it working by changing a lot here is my version if you want to have a look at it:

At the String `text` the whole string, that is going to get split up, is passed in:

```java
text=text+"\n   ";
String[] splits = null;
String[] lines = null;
int numbSplits =0;
int numbLines =0;
int run = 0;
while(text.length()>4) {

    //DEBUG
    run++;
    try{
        Thread.sleep(100);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException ex){
    }
    System.out.println("LENGHT: " +text.length());
    System.out.println("NEXT TAB " + text.indexOf(" ") + " NEXT LINE " + text.indexOf("\n"));
    if(run == 5||run == 10||run == 15||run == 20) {
        System.out.println(text);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1300);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex){}
    }
    if(run==20) {
        break;
    }

    //DEBUG
    if(text.indexOf("\n")>text.indexOf("    ")) {
        splits=text.split(" ",0);
        spanischList.add(splits[0]);
        text=text.replaceFirst(spanischList.get(numbSplits), "");
        text=text.replaceFirst("    ", "");
        splits=null;
        numbSplits++;
    }
    else if(text.indexOf("\n")<text.indexOf("   ")) {
        lines=text.split("\n");
        deutschList.add(lines[0]);
        text=text.replaceFirst(deutschList.get(numbLines), "");
        text=text.replaceFirst("\n", "");
        lines=null;
        numbLines++;
        nrOfVoc +=1;
    }
}
```

(You can comment out that `DEBUG`, it is just for debugging...)

And at my PC it can't cope with öäüñ cause my PC won't let me change its encoding to UTF-8, but that's another story...

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Do you get an Error/Exception when you run the code? If yes please add the error message and stacktrace. Or do you get a result you don't expect? If yes please add this result and how it differs from what you want to your question.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't use C-style comments to post what is basically the text of your question. It rendered as a dotted list, it was a mess to fix and we shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: What exactly is not working? -> The spliting of the string does not work as I intendet it to. For example splits[2] is deut2 voc3; but it should contain only voc2. (like i wrote in the discription - and the for loop is just to run it less often, to put out less debug messages, in the final Version would the main part run in a while until text.isEmty=true)

Comment: Frederico klez Cullaca, thank you for reformating, sorry this was my first Stack Overflow post!

Answer (score 0):

Using this as your input:

```java
String text= "voc1  deut1\nvoc2 deut2\nvoc3 deut3\nvoc4 deut4";
```

and this as your desired output:

```
splits[0]="voc1"
splits[1]="voc2"
splits[2]="voc3"
splits[3]="voc4"

lines[0]="deut1"
lines[1]="deut2"
lines[2]="deut3"
lines[3]="deut4"
```

The following is my implementation:

```java
public class Replacer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text= "voc1  deut1\nvoc2 deut2\nvoc3 deut3\nvoc4 deut4";
        String[] rows = text.split("\n");
        String[] splits = new String[rows.length];
        String[] lines = new String[rows.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            String[] parts = rows[i].split("\\s+");
            splits[i] = parts[0];
            lines[i] = parts[1];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("splits[%d]=\"%s\"%n", i, splits[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            System.out.printf("lines[%d]=\"%s\"%n", i, lines[i]);
        }
    }
}
```